# Is a rand from glibc's rand secure for a login key?

Tags: authentication, linux, random

Same question as [Is a rand from /dev/urandom secure for a login key](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3936/is-a-rand-from-dev-urandom-secure-for-a-login-key), but with glibc's `rand` function instead of `/dev/urandom`. And what would be a sufficiently secure seed generator?

Answer (score 17):

No. The [PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) in typical C libraries is designed for speed, not for security. It's usually appropriate for numerical simulations and games (in good-quality implementations — there are implementations out there, mostly old ones, where it's not appropriate for anything), but not for cryptography. A [cryptographic PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator#Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generators) must be unpredictable, i.e. an attacker who generates a series of numbers must not be able to make a good guess at the next number. The typical C library PRNG strives for speed and good statistical properties but not for unpredictability.

As of Glibc 2.7, `rand` and friends use a [linear congruential PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) or a [linear feedback shift register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register) depending on the available seed length.

To generate key material or any other random number involved in cryptography (including non-secret things like nonces that nonetheless need to be unpredictable), obtain all bits from a crypto-quality RNG. Linux's `/dev/urandom` (or any other unix that has `/dev/urandom`) is fine for that. You must use it for each byte of each key; using it as a seed of the C library PRNG is not good (there would be a strong correlation between the keys). A library such as [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) is another choice; it'll probably use `/dev/urandom` under the hood as a seed but may be a little faster if you're generating large volumes of random data.

Comment: Another thing to note (a quite important one, imho) is that the C standard makes no guarantee of the algorithm in question which means that if you switch the libc or compiler or platform you may find yourself in a nasty spot. Just because a particular implementation happens to maybe use something cryptographycally-secure does not mean it is safe to rely on that. When writing something in a language that's implemented in a lot of compilers it makes sense to rely only on what the specification guarantees.

Comment: @Joey I thought I'd covered that with “there are implementations out there (…) where it's not appropriate for anything”; do you think my answer needs clarification or reinforcement?

Answer (score 5):

No!  `rand()` is totally insecure.  Using `rand()` for this purpose has caused [major vulnerabilities in major systems](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~daw/papers/ddj-netscape.html).

Just use `/dev/urandom`.