# Requirements for a secure session id?

Tags: session-management, random

I'm writing a web service which stores data which will be shared between two
separate systems.

`/session/requestNewSession?args=<data>` => returns session id

`/session/requestArgs?session=<session id>` => returns `<data>` stored with key `<session id>`

The code is implemented in python in the twisted matrix library, and I've written my own session id generator:

```
private_secret = os.urandom(64)
def generateRandomSessionKey():
 rawdata = private_secret + str(time.time()) + string.join(map(chr, [random.randint(0,255) for x in range(100)]),"")
 session_key = hashlib.sha256(rawdata).hexdigest()
 del(rawdata)
 return session_key
```

Is this a proper way of generating a secure session id (unguessable)? If not, any ideas on what I should do differently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer.** Yes.  This is a fine way to generate a session ID.

**Rationale.** The `private_secret` will be unguessable and cryptographically strong (that is guaranteed by `urandom()`).  So, all you need is that the combination of `time.time()` and your `random.randint()` numbers are unique: that combination should never repeat.  That should be pretty much guaranteed.  The Python random number generator shouldn't repeat for a long time, so you should be fine.

For more, see [Is a rand from /dev/urandom secure for a login key?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/3936/971) for a related question.

**Caveat.**  The only risk factor I can see would be: if you run the server process in a VM, starting from the same checkpoint every time.  (In other words, before deployment you boot up the guest OS in the VM once and checkpoint it at that point; then every time you start up your web service, you start it up from that checkpoint.)  In that situation, `os.urandom()`, `time.time()`, and `random.randint()` could all repeat, causing you to allocate the same session ID to two different clients.  But as long as you don't use a VM in that way, you should be fine.

**An alternative.** A simpler way and just-as-secure implementation would be to use the following:

```
def generateRandomSessionKey():
    return hexify(os.urandom(16))
```

Comment: +1 for the much shorter and more elegant solution. If you must implement your own sessions, then **keep it simple**. If you already use a good enough random source, adding time() won't help much but just makes things slower and more complicated (same goes to string joins, maps etc)... complicated == more chances of errors.

Comment: cannot excessive use of os.urandom() block on some OS implementations?

Comment: @Dogeatcatworld, no: as far as I know `os.urandom()` will never block.  At least, not on any OS platform I am familiar with.  (On Unix, internally it uses `/dev/urandom`, not `/dev/random`.  `/dev/urandom` doesn't block -- you may be thinking of `/dev/random`, which can block, but you should always use `/dev/urandom` not `/dev/random`.  On Windows, it uses `CryptGenRandom()`, which should never block, either.)